# Converter arquivos .py para arquivos .exe

Tags: python, conversão, .exe

Olá, alguém consegue me explicar como converter um aplicativo em formato .py para .exe e executar no windows? Tentei usar o cx_freeze mas não consegui. Tem como criar um conversor? Valeu.

Comment: Já tentou usar o `pyinstaller` ?

Comment: Não, estou tentando entender como funciona agora. Mas estou batendo cabeça em como instalar e utilizar o mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

se deseja ter **obrigatoriamente** um .exe, utilize o pyinstaller. Lembrando que terá que instalá-lo.

`pyinstaller <nome_do_arquivo>`

caso queira ter um arquivo binário, utilize o py_compile que já vem com os utilitários do python.

`python3 -m py_compile <nome_do_arquivo>`